# IntegrityError -userprofile.u_id may not be NULL, django user registration

Tags: django, null, save, django-users

I am trying to register users using the Django UserProfile capability. I have an Extended UserProfile model. My files look like below. I am getting "accounts_userprofile.u_id may not be NULL', i tried using 'commit=false' when saving the form, but it didn't work. My parent model has the fields set to null= True, blank = True. I have dropped the table and added it a couple of times, but nothing worked. Please help. Thanks in advance

My Models are below:

```
class UserBase(models.Model):
class Meta:
    abstract = True
    u_id = models.IntegerField(null = True,blank = True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True,blank = True)
    website=models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True, blank = True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null=True, blank = True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
```

The UserProfile Model is as follows:

```
class UserProfile(UserBase):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null= True, blank = True, unique = True)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0]) 
def __unicode__(self):
    return "User Profile for: " + self.user.username
```

def create_user_profile(sender, **kw):
    user = kw['instance']
    if kw['created']:
        up = UserProfile(user=user)

```
    up.save()
```

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender = User, dispatch_uid ="user_create_profile")

My registration View is below:

> def register(request, template_name="registration/register.html"):
>     if request.method == 'POST':
>
> ```
>   postdata = request.POST.copy()
>   form = UserCreationForm(postdata)
>   if form.is_valid(): 
>
>       un = postdata.get('username','')
>       pw = postdata.get('password1','')
>
>       from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
>
>       new_user = authenticate(username=un, password=pw)
>       form.save()
>       #if new_user and new_user.is_active:
>           #login(request, new_user)
>           #url = urlresolvers.reverse('my_account')
>           #return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
> ```
>
> else:
>         form = UserCreationForm()
>         page_title = 'User Registration'
>     return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
>     context_instance=RequestContext(request))>

Comment: could you post the traceback ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Django Docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/

> Field.unique
>
> If True, this field must be unique throughout the table.
>
> This is enforced at the database level and by model validation. If you
>   try to save a model with a duplicate value in a unique field, a
>   django.db.IntegrityError will be raised by the model's save() method.
>
> This option is valid on all field types except ManyToManyField and
>   FileField.

You are telling UserProfiles that the UserProfiles.u_id is unique, it's not (blanks/null). So you're getting the error. You may want to consider changing u_id to be a AutoField primary_key. And then connect them using models.ForeignKey('UserBase')